# Upload audio video files in Wordpress post/page

Tags: wordpress

How could I upload audio/video files in my wordpress post or page?
Indeed there is an icon buttons to upload both type of files but when I used the **Add Video** button, browse a video file & update my post, I surprised that it only showed a link of that video file and when I vied it's HTML there were no tag of  ....
So how it is possible to add audio/video file in wordpress post/page form my **Dashboard Panel** means I don't want to copy/paste **embed** code from youtube or some where else in my HTML code.
Like for audio I found

```
[audio http://wpcom.files.wordpress.com/2007/01/mattmullenweg-interview.mp3|width=180]
```

similarly for video I found

```
<embed src="http://wpcom.files.wordpress.com/2007/01/mattmullenweg-interview.mp3" width=180></embed>
```

that are not the best way to add 100s of audio/video files in Wordpress post/page..!

Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to display a video in Wordpress you need to embed using the HTML5 "Video for everybody" method or another video player.  There are plugins that help you achieve this.